# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I created a jaxws web service. I totally followed the [url](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-java-web-application-integration-example/)

The service was up perfectly without any error. But the server having errors when request hit it.

```
SEVERE: caught throwable
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory.newContext(JAXBRIContextFactory.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.create(JAXBMessage.java:160)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAP11Fault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:433)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:210)
```

I checked through out stackoverflow and many other sites all says jar file conflict. 
I use java-6-openjdk. 
 
and below is my jar file list in the jetty server.

> gmbal-api-only.jar 
>  ha-api.jar
>  jaxb-core.jar 
>   jaxb-impl.jar 
>  jaxws-rt.jar 
>  management-api.jar 
>   policy-2.3.1.jar 
>  stax-ex.jar 
>  streambuffer-1.5.1.jar

Since above jars are not working I tried with  
Go [here](http://jax-ws.java.net/) 
Download JAX-WS RI distribution.

But those jars gave the same error.

Comment: Showing us your code might help a bit.

Comment: Hi,
the code is in there in the 
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-java-web-application-integration-example/
I didn't add here, because everything is clear in that tutorial.
I can start the service without any problem and can see the wsdl perfectly.

Comment: I has this exact same error - it turned out that it was caused by a NullPointerException on the server side. Fixing the NPE resolved the issue!

Answer (score 3):

I have also came across same exception and little bit googling it confirmed that its because of classpath/jar issue.

I'm using Java 6.0 as build and runtime environment and my project setup having **jaxb-api.jar and jaxb-impl.jar**. **I simply removed these two jars from classpath and it works.**

As if we are having Java 6.0 we dont need to use explicitely JAX binding jars. It comes by default with Java 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Check this thread: [web client for web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093889/web-client-for-web-service). The main problem I think is that you have several jaxb jars that differ in versions. For example, I think that jaxb is already part of jaxws-rt.jar which would mean you don't need jaxb-core.jar and jaxb-impl.jar.

Comment: HI,
I can't remove any of above jar and that gave different no class found errors.
ie. if I remove the jar files u mentioned that gave me va.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/istack/localization/Localizable

Can any body give me working jar file set? That is the best solution I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Same error occured on my Java 7 project. Removing
com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar
com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc-2.2.6.jar

dependencies solved the problem.

Alternative solution :

clientPort is an Interface with @WebService annotation.

```
    BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) clientPort;        
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointUrl);
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, serviceUsername);
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, servicePassword);
```

Comment: And also    System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext", "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory");
  System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");