# How to add axis web service jar in mobilefirst adapter

Tags: java, maven, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have implemented a Java Adapter in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0. In this adapter I would like to integrate with web Services Client Jax-WS. I had called the services from generated client by eclipse. But when I built the program ( `mvn install` ), it's showing errors, it seems I cannot get the axis lib.

```
.... package org.apache.axis.client does not exist

lib:
axis-ant.jar
axis.jar
.......
```

Anyone can help me for this errors. Do I need to add in pom.xml dependency to get the lib because this jar is generated.

Comment: MobileFirst server sits on a Java EE server. Which are you using? In WebSphere, for instance, if you specifically use `org.apache.axis` classes, you might not have access to them without packaging them in your pom and adapter. Do you need the Axis classes specifically, as opposed to just using the jax-ws ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Java adapters are based on the **JAX-RS** specification and expose a full REST API to the client. In other words, a Java adapter is a JAX-RS service that can be deployed to MobileFirst Server.

Refer: [Java adapters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_of_ibm_java_adap.html)

Comment: thanks for the info, how about JAX-RS in adapter call existing record from JAX-WS Service..

Comment: If your looking at invoking the WS from the adapter, yes that is possible. You can refer to the sample [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/java-http-adapter/)

Comment: thanks, i'll move to using java Http, but when i read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33077089/6042785 , it view that MobileFirst have problem with jax-ws lib, web services client in java.

Comment: Does MobileFirst Server support axis.jar axis-ant.jar lib...can anyone confirm?